# CSS menu aligns to left but when floating to right, the order of menu items are reversed

Tags: css-float, right-to-left

I know others have asked this question and I'm not able to wrap my head around those solutions due to the complexity of the CSS being used and I have submenus within. This was made by an online menu CSS generator. This is the page that I'm building:

http://sandboxisle.com/home-page-main/

```css
#menu {
    background: #00338D;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 45px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#menu ul, #menu li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul {
    width: 100%;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
#menu a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EBB700;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#menu a.dropdown-arrow:after {
    content: "\25BE";
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #00338D;
}
#menu input {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer
}
#menu label {
    display: none;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px
}
#menu label:before {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    content: "\2261"; 
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#menu ul.sub-menus{
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    background: #766A62;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    display: none;
}
#menu ul.sub-menus li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu ul.sub-menus a {
    color: #EBB700;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#menu li:hover ul.sub-menus {
    display: block
}
#menu ul.sub-menus a:hover{
    background: #766A62;
    color: #ffffff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    #menu {position:relative}
    #menu ul {background:#766A62;position:absolute;top:100%;right:0;left:0;z-index:3;height:auto;display:none}
    #menu ul.sub-menus {width:100%;position:static;}
    #menu ul.sub-menus a {padding-left:30px;}
    #menu li {display:block;float:none;width:auto;}
    #menu input, #menu label {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:block}
    #menu input {z-index:4}
    #menu input:checked + label {color:white}
    #menu input:checked + label:before {content:"\00d7"}
    #menu input:checked ~ ul {display:block}
}
```

Here's my HTML

```html
<nav id='menu'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='responsive-menu' onclick='updatemenu()'><label></label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='Calendar'>Calendar</a></li>
    <li><a href='News'>News</a></li>
    <li><a class='dropdown-arrow' href='For Members'>For Members</a>
      <ul class='sub-menus'>
        <li><a href='Orientation'>Orientation</a></li>
        <li><a href='Leadership Building'>Leadership Building</a></li>
        <li><a href='Newsletters'>Newsletters</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class='dropdown-arrow' href='Resource'>Resource</a>
      <ul class='sub-menus'>
        <li><a href='Service Documents'>Service Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href='District 50 Clubs Directory'>District 50 Clubs Directory</a></li>
        <li><a href='Awards & Contests'>Awards & Contests</a></li>
        <li><a href='D50 Resource'>D50 Resource</a></li>
        <li><a href='Club Resource'>Club Resource</a></li>
        <li><a href='LCIF Resource'>LCIF Resource</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code below:

```css
#menu {
  background: #00338d;
  color: #fff;
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu .navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ebb700;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#menu a.dropdown-arrow:after {
  content: "\25BE";
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #00338d;
}
#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menu label {
  display: none;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
}
#menu label:before {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  content: "\2261";
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#menu ul.sub-menus {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  background: #766a62;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
}
#menu ul.sub-menus li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu ul.sub-menus a {
  color: #ebb700;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#menu li:hover ul.sub-menus {
  display: block;
}
#menu ul.sub-menus a:hover {
  background: #766a62;
  color: #ffffff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #menu {
    position: relative;
  }
  #menu ul {
    background: #766a62;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
  }
  #menu ul.sub-menus {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
  }
  #menu ul.sub-menus a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  #menu li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
  #menu input,
  #menu label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  #menu input {
    z-index: 4;
  }
  #menu input:checked + label {
    color: white;
  }
  #menu input:checked + label:before {
    content: "\00d7";
  }
  #menu input:checked ~ ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="responsive-menu"
        onclick="updatemenu()"
      /><label></label>
      <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="Calendar">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="News">News</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-arrow" href="For Members">For Members</a>
          <ul class="sub-menus">
            <li><a href="Orientation">Orientation</a></li>
            <li><a href="Leadership Building">Leadership Building</a></li>
            <li><a href="Newsletters">Newsletters</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-arrow" href="Resource">Resource</a>
          <ul class="sub-menus">
            <li><a href="Service Documents">Service Documents</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="District 50 Clubs Directory"
                >District 50 Clubs Directory</a
              >
            </li>
            <li><a href="Awards & Contests">Awards & Contests</a></li>
            <li><a href="D50 Resource">D50 Resource</a></li>
            <li><a href="Club Resource">Club Resource</a></li>
            <li><a href="LCIF Resource">LCIF Resource</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).